# ValueError: Input 0 of layer lstm is incompatible with the layer: expected ndim=3, found ndim=4. Full shape received: [None, 7, 5, 4]

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, lstm

`self.LSTM  = LSTM((1),input_shape=[7,5, 4])`

This is how i have defined my LSTM layer, here 5 are the no of timesteps and 4 are no of features and 7 are no of agents, I want the output in the shape of [batchsize,7,4] but I am getting the error "ValueError: Input 0 of layer lstm is incompatible with the layer: expected ndim=3, found ndim=4. Full shape received: [None, 7, 5, 4]"

Any idea how I can implement this ?

Comment: A `LSTM`  layer takes a 2D input shape (excluding the batch size) not 3D

Comment: I know that but what should i do in order to implement this in LSTM flattening array the matrix is an option but wouldn't it damage the meaning of the agent positions ?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

LSTM takes inputs: A 3D tensor with shape `[batch, timesteps, feature]`

```
import tensorflow as tf
inputs = tf.random.normal([7, 5, 4])
lstm = tf.keras.layers.LSTM(4, return_sequences=True)
output = lstm(inputs)
print(output.shape)
```

**Output**

```
(7, 5, 4)
```